# How to add virtual optical drive on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I wanted to have a shared folder on D letter. So I deleted optical drive which was using D letter.

How to add it back (on letter E) ?

Comment: How did you delete it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have just change the drive letter instead of removing the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Drive letter in the Disk Management snap-in in Windows.

If you deleted a drive you add back by going to storage devices in the Storage section of the setting for the VM. Click on the IDE controller and then click on the "Add new optical drive".